# function for language C which has same as sparse in Matlab

Tags: c, matlab, sparse-matrix

I want to assemble a lot of small local matrices into one global sparse matrix.
And also after assembly process I need another functions for deleting some specific row and column at the global sparse matrix.

So the best option is "sparse" in Matlab. However, I want use this kind of function in Language C.
Is there any function or library for using this kind of function in language C?

Comment: The C language doesn’t have a type representing a matrix. You will have to look for a matrix or linear algebra  library. Asking for library recommendations is off topic here. Try https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Have you looked at the Wiki article for sparse matrices?  It lists software packages in various languages.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you plan to use the assembled sparse matrix, and what is the library you want to use to achieve so. the format you use to store such sparse matrix in memory in C is pretty much determined by these library's supported inputs.

for example, you can use [SuiteSparse](https://people.engr.tamu.edu/davis/suitesparse.html) libraries to solve linear equations, such as [UMFPACK](https://people.math.sc.edu/Burkardt/cpp_src/umfpack/umfpack.html) - it takes in a [Compress Column (CC) format](https://people.sc.fsu.edu/%7Ejburkardt/data/cc/cc.html) to store a sparse matrix. Other libraries may need other different formats.